# Regex to finding any kind of uuid or random generated text

Tags: regex, url, random, uuid, matching

I want to find any kind of uuid or random generated text in a url path and replace it with `<random>`. Examples :

1. `/test/ajs1d5haFkajs1dhasdd2as345sdAS3+Ddas9` = `/test/<random>`
2. `/test/akKd9Ja3/ajs1d5haFkajs1ddasd623ha5sdAS3Ddas9=/30` = `/test/<random>/<random>/30`
3. `/test/akKd9Ja3/Example-ASDAdddasd-108174.js` = `/test/<random>/Example-108174.js`.
4. `/test/akKd9Ja3-ASj83asj-dask92qwe_ke` = `/test/<random>`

I'm looking for a solution that will match on a string:

- starting with `/` AND
- end with `/` or `$`
- contain `[0-9]` AND
- contain `[a-z]` OR `[A-Z]`
- CAN contain `-`, `=`, `_`, `+`, `\s` (spa
- DOES NOT contain an extension i.e `.<something>`
- 7 char and longer `{7,}`

This is what I used so far :
`/[a-zA-Z0-9-=_+\s]{30,}`

This works for most cases since uuids are often longer than 30 char. But I don't catch the **small ones** i.e `/5c88148/` or `/6qdkKdk5/`. I also match on things like `Example-ASDAddasd-108174.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - In case you want match must contain at least one digit.You can use this.

```
(?<=\/)(?=[\w-+=\s]+[0-9])[\w-+=\s]{7,}(?![.])(?!\.)(?=\/|\n)
```

[Demo for update](https://regex101.com/r/5abANS/7)

You can try this.

```
(?<=\/)[\w-+=\s]{7,}(?!\.)(?=\/|\n)
```

> Explanation

- `(?<=\/)` - Positive look behind. Matches '/'.
- `[\w-+=\s]{7,}` - Matches any word character, `-`,`+`,`=`, and space 7 or more time.
- `(?!\.)` - Negative look ahead. Do not match `.`.
- `(?=\/|\n)` - Positive look ahead. Matches '/' or '\n'(New line).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5abANS/4)

Comment: This is really close! Thanks for you answer. But it's also matching on things without capital letters or numbers: `/filestreamingservice/as88ASD8asd` or `/graphic_new/asdasAD7afasfa` the `\w` is to global it think.

Comment: @HansDaigle check the answer i have updated regex for that case too.